# How to Transfer a number in an array from one position to another

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I would like to know how to transfer a number.

For example: `[1,0,2,3,4]`

Remove the one and transfer the one to two's position

Result: `[0,0,1,3,4]`

Comment: what have you tried that didn't work out?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your manipulations are purely index-based, you can do this:

```
lst = [1,0,2,3,4]
lst[2] = lst[0]
lst[0] = 0

# [0, 0, 1, 3, 4]
```

Alternatively, if you need to work out the index of 2:

```
lst[lst.index(2)] = lst[0]
lst[0] = 0
```

Comment: If I multiple arrays which are taken from a text file                                                   [1,2,3,4,0], [1,3,2,4,0] , [2,1,3,4,0] and I want to change the 1 to 2's position without assigning variables for each array?

Comment: @Watallapan, then ask as a separate question! That's not what you asked initially..

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not described your question with clear instructions, There is case when there will be more than one 2 or 1 in vector then what you want to do ?

My solution is only for that condition when there is single 1 and 2 in vector because when you use .index method it always returns first value index no matter there are other values too.

Since in your dataset there is always 1 times 1 and 2 in all vector so here is the solution for that

```
data=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 0], [1, 3, 2, 4, 0], [2, 1, 3, 4, 0] ]

def replace_ (vector_ , replace_value, replace_with):

    memory=vector_.index(replace_with)

    vector_[vector_.index(replace_value)]=vector_[vector_.index(replace_with)]

    vector_[memory]=0


    return vector_


for i in data:
    print(replace_(i,1,2))
```

If there are more than one 1 or 2 in vector like `[1,0,1,1,2,2]` then describe your logic and edit your question for that.